# JS: Change image name on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add '_hover.jpg' to my images on mouse over, but I'm struggling! Any help much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {


$(".img").mouseover(function (e) {    
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".jpg", "_hover.jpg"));
}).mouseout(function (e) {
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("._hover.jpg", ".jpg"));
});

)}
```

```
<li class="hex">
<div class="hexIn">
<img src="/images/leaderboard.jpg" alt="" class="hex-img"/>
  <h2>Joe Bloggs<br>from ACME<br>volunteered at<br>Inspire<br>on 3 July</h2>
</div></li>
```

Many thanks

Comment: change your `.img` to `hex-img` in `$(".img").mouseover(function (e) {  `

Comment: What @Curiousdev said, or do with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".hex-img").mouseover(function () {    
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".jpg", "_hover.jpg"));
$(".test").text($(this).attr("src"));
}).mouseout(function () {
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("_hover.jpg", ".jpg"));
$(".test").text($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="test">Hello</p>
<li class="hex">
<div class="hexIn">
<img src="abc.jpg" class="hex-img" width="100px" height="100px"/>
  <h2>Joe Bloggs<br>from ACME<br>volunteered at<br>Inspire<br>on 3 July</h2>
</div></li>
```

Comment: Possible to do this exact same thing without jquery? As easily I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.hex-img:hover {
background-image: url('_hover.jpg');
}

.hex-img {
background-image: url('original.jpg');
}
</style>
```

Comment: its changing the `src` of the image

Comment: you have to add this too
<style>
.hex-img {
background-image: url('initial.jpg');
}
</style>

Answer (score 1):

Selector was wrong its a `img` not `.img`. its represent the class name.But your classname is `hex-img` .And `document.ready` not closing proberly .closing was wrong .Its a `})` instead of `)}`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("img").mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".jpg", "_hover.jpg"));
        console.log($(this).attr("src"))
      }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("._hover.jpg", ".jpg"));
        console.log($(this).attr("src"))
      });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="hex">
  <div class="hexIn">
    <img src="/images/leaderboard.jpg" alt="" class="hex-img" />
    <h2>Joe Bloggs<br>from ACME<br>volunteered at<br>Inspire<br>on 3 July</h2>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks that's sorted adding the _hover.jpg, but it doesn't remove it again. In fact, it keeps adding _hover.jpg every time instead (see code snippet.)  It also removes the child of formatting that I have in my style sheet for this div class-  any thoughts why?

Comment: I've worked out why I lost my formatting on the child - because my script was within my <ul> brackets! Any input on how to restore the original image on mouse out much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a default html tag you dont need to add `.` or `#` ..But that is not a professional way..always select based on `id` or `class` Change this line..

```
$(".hex-img").mouseover(function (e) {
```

Comment: That was not the problem

Comment: sorry for that..little confusion